# Are there tensor structures other than a metric which could be defined on a manifold which imply a connection through compatibility criterion?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

If we say our connection is torsion free, then the metric compatibility condition completely determines it. While this is geometrically intuitive way to do it, are there other interesting tensor fields which we can put on a manifold whom when we impose a compatibility condition with the connection that we uniquely get the connection?

Comment: Sometimes, to a geometric structure, one can find a unique connection that is compatible. This is the case of the Levi-Civita connection in Riemannian geometry. This is also the case with the Tanaka-Webster connection and its associated curvature tensor in CR geometry. In conformal geometry (and in dimension greater than $3$), the Weyl tensor is a sort of curvature tensor that is a conformal invariant and can be recovered from what is called a Cartan connection (generalizing affine connections)

Comment: To add a simpler example, a trivialization of the tangent bundle is a tensorial structure which induces a unique connection which vanishes  on "constant" sections. These are used on Lie groups, for instance.